# Jquery Draggable Function not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-ui

I have a JSP page where i am trying and make rows of one of the tables in my page draggable but it isn't happening . The Rows of the tables gets appended to it after an AJAX call . I have tried various combinations and everything but i can't get any of my elements to be draggable .

Here's my page

```html
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
 pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="sec"
 uri="http://www.springframework.org/security/tags"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
<title>Categories</title>
<link rel="stylesheet"
 href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet"
 href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href='<c:url value="/static/css/header.css" />'>
<script
 src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script
 src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script
 src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.9/jquery.validate.js"></script>

<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<script src="http://dev.jquery.com/view/tags/ui/latest/ui/ui.core.js"></script>
  <script src="http://dev.jquery.com/view/tags/ui/latest/ui/ui.draggable.js"></script>

<script
 src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.9/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">

table {
    table-layout: fixed;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}

th {
text-align:center;
}
#serviceSelect {
 text-align: center;
}

#serviceSelect {
 margin: auto;
 width: 30%;
}
#removeSelect {
 text-align: center;
}

#removeSelect {
 margin: auto;
 width: 30%;
}

#123 {
 margin: auto;
 width: 50%;
}
p {
 font:bold;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
 <jsp:include page="../shared/header.jsp">
  <jsp:param value="editActionButtons" name="currentPage" />
 </jsp:include>
 <div class="row">
  <div class="text-center">
   <h2>Select Service</h2>
   <div class="text-muted">
    <h4>Choose a Service To Edit Its Action Buttons</h4>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="form-group" id="serviceSelect">
  <select class="form-control" id="serviceMenu">
     <option value="" disabled selected>Select Service</option>
   <c:forEach items="${service}" var="seritem">
     <option>${seritem}</option>
   </c:forEach>
  </select>
 </div>
 <br></br>

 <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" action="updateActionButton" method=POST id="form2">
<div class="table-responsive12">
        <table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-highlight" id="tab_logic">
  </table> 
  <table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-highlight">
     <tr id="submit">
     
     <td colspan="3" align="center">
  <div class="form-group">
   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-md" id="submit">Submit</button>
  </div>
  </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</div> 
</form>
<br></br>
      <form class='form-horizontal' role='form' action='removeActionButton' method=POST>
      <div class="sel" id="123"></div>
      </form>
      <form class='form-horizontal' role='form' action='addActionButton' method=POST>
      <div class="sel1" id="1234"></div>
      </form>
 
<script type="text/javascript">
var t;
  $(function() {
   
   $("#serviceMenu").change(function() {
    var service = $("#serviceMenu").val(); 
    loadData(service);
                loadTable(t);
                loadActionData();
                remove();
                add();
                $("#submit").draggable();
       $("#tab_logic").draggable();
       $("#tab_logic tr").draggable();
   });
   $("#submit").draggable();
   $("#tab_logic").draggable();
   $("#tab_logic tr").draggable();
   
   
});
  
  
  function loadData(service) {
   $.ajax({
    type : "GET",
    data : {
     serv : service
    },
    dataType : 'json',
    async : false ,
    url : "printServiceDetails",
    success : function(data) {
     t=data; 
     
    },
    error : function() {
     alert("error");
    }

   });
  }
  
  function loadTable(num) {
   $('#tab_logic').empty();
   
   for (var i=1 ;i<=num;i++)   {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
   $('#tab_logic').append("<tr><td colspan='3' align='center'><p id='addrp"+i+"'><strong>Action Button "+i+" Properties</strong></p></td></tr>");
   $('#tab_logic').append("<tr><td align='center' style='width:15%'><p id='addac"+i+"'><strong>Action</strong></p></td><td class='text-danger' align='center' style='width:15%'><p id='addpac"+i+"'>Action</p></td><td><input type ='text' class ='form-control' id='addiac"+i+"' name ='addiac"+i+"' placeholder='Enter Action'</td> </tr>");
   $('#tab_logic').append("<tr><td align='center' style='width:15%'><p id='addat"+i+"'><strong>Action Text</strong></p></td><td class='text-danger' align='center' style='width:15%'><p id='addpat"+i+"'>Action Text</p></td><td><input type ='text' class ='form-control' id='addiat"+i+"' name ='addiat"+i+"' placeholder='Enter Action Text'</td> </tr>");
   $('#tab_logic').append("<tr><td align='center' style='width:15%'><p id='addcc"+i+"'><strong>Color Code</strong></p></td><td class='text-danger' align='center' style='width:15%'><p id='addpcc"+i+"'>Color Code</p></td><td><input type ='text' class ='form-control' id='addicc"+i+"' name ='addicc"+i+"' placeholder='Enter Color Code'</td> </tr>");
   
   
   }
   
  }
  
  function loadActionData() {
   $.ajax({
    type : "GET",
    dataType : 'json',
    async : false ,
    url : "loadButtonDetails",
    success : function(data) {
    
     for(var i=1;i<=data.length;i++)
      {
      $("#addpac"+i.toString()).html("<strong>"+data[i-1].ac+"</strong>");
      $("#addpcc"+i.toString()).html("<strong>"+data[i-1].cc+"</strong>");
      $("#addpat"+i.toString()).html("<strong>"+data[i-1].at+"</strong>");
      $("#addiac"+i.toString()).val(data[i-1].ac);
      $("#addicc"+i.toString()).val(data[i-1].cc);
      $("#addiat"+i.toString()).val(data[i-1].at);
      }
    
    },
    error : function() {
     alert("error");
    }
   });  
  }
  function remove(){
   var htm="";
   $("#123").html(htm);
   htm+="<div class='text-center'><h4><strong>ADD/DELETE ACTION BUTTONS</strong></h4></div>";
   htm+="<select class='form-control id='removeSelect' name='removeSelect' style='width:30%;text-align:center;margin:auto'>";
   for(var i=1;i<=t;i++)
   {
    htm+="<option>"+i+"</option>";
   }
   htm+="</select>";
   htm+="<div style='text-align:center'><button type='submit' class='btn btn-success btn-md' id='removeSubmit'>Remove</button> </div>";
   $("#123").append(htm);
  }
  function add(){
   var htm="";
   $("#1234").html(htm);
   htm+="<div class='text-center'><h4>Enter The Details To Add A Button</h4></div>";
         htm+="<table class='table table-bordered table-striped table-highlight'><tr> <th>Action</th><th>Action Text</th><th>Color Code</th></tr>";
         htm+="<tr><td><input type='text' class='form-control' id='ac' name='ac' placeholder='Enter Action'></td><td><input type='text' class='form-control' id='at' name='at' placeholder='Enter Action text'></td><td><input type='text' class='form-control' id='cc' name='cc' placeholder='Enter Color Code'></td></tr>";
   htm+="</table>";
   htm+="<div style='text-align:center'><button type='submit' class='btn btn-success btn-md' id='addSubmit'>Add</button> </div>";
   $("#1234").append(htm);
  }

 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to tell jQuery-UI which DOM elements are draggable. There is a method you have to call for that. Check the docs here:

https://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#option-addClasses

```
$('.yourRows').draggable()
```

Just select the nodes with jQuery and call the `draggable` method. MAKE SURE you do this after the DOM nodes are appended after your AJAX call.

Comment: Thanks .Its working now . I am also using the sortable funcion of jqery to rearrange the rows of the table . But instead of sorting individual rows , I want the user to sort the rows in a group of four . as in my code ( The name + the three properties of it ) . Can you please help me as to how i can achieve this as i am really new to jquery

Comment: You could wrap each group of four in a <div>. You can give these divs a class and make those outer divs sortable instead.